# How to convert the result from Soap Webservice and show in blade laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, soap, call

I want to get and call data from Soap webservices based on Application No (AppNo)

```html
 $soapclient = new SoapClient('http://192.168.0.xxx/xxx/MOMCallWS.asmx?WSDL');

     $AppNo = '29d53966afe24026a0250153e4a85f7b';
        $txnCode = 'ST003';
        $ActCode = 'R';
        $usr = 'xxxx';
        $pwd = 'xxx';
 $params = [
                'AppNo' => request()->input('AppNo') ? request()->input('AppNo') : $AppNo,
                'txnCode'   => request()->input('txnCode') ? request()->input('txnCode') : $txnCode,
                'ActCode' => request()->input('ActCode') ? request()->input('ActCode') : $ActCode,
                'usr'   => request()->input('usr') ? request()->input('usr') : $usr,
                'pwd' => request()->input('pwd') ? request()->input('pwd') : $pwd
            ];
        $response = $soapclient->MOMCallStat($params);
        var_dump($response);
        dd($response);
         exit;
```

and here is the result 
[image]

in the mark area, you can see all the result, there are APP NO, NAME, DATE ,etc
how to show date in blade,

when i use this code in blade
{{$response->AppNo}}

{{$response->ApvAm}}

etc

i got this error
[image]

Comment: did you got any error ?

Comment: no error, but i dont know how to show it in blade, i updated my latest result in above, please help me

Comment: what if you convert this to array by : $response =  (array)  $soapclient->MOMCallStat($params); and access this as index